# How to properly include HTML in android project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to make an app, but I don't know anything about Java.
I've decided to add a webpage to my app, which would include all the required styling and logic from JavaScript.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

However,  I get error:

```
Error:(13, 53) error: cannot find symbol variable webView
Error:(13, 9) error: cannot find symbol class WebView
Error:(13, 28) error: cannot find symbol class WebView
```

Comment: take look at wrappers like https://phonegap.com/ or https://ionicframework.com/ that you can use native api in js and build your app using web tech and export for multi platform.

Answer (score 0):

You must add

> import android.webkit.WebView;